# Postgres SQL to fill in time series gaps for multiple groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a single table like this which spans 2 days of data capture:

```
   class   timestamp              count

   2       2020-05-20 03:10:00    4
   1       2020-05-21 07:45:00    2
   6       2020-05-20 09:20:00    1
   2       2020-05-21 11:30:00    1
   5       2020-05-21 21:50:00    3
   1       2020-05-21 07:45:00    5
   5       2020-05-20 14:55:00    2
```

I would like to create output similar to that schema but with **every** 5 minute interval over the two days represented with count zeroed out if there is no matching timestamp.  All duplicate timestamps for a class need to be totaled for that timestamp entry.  All the unique classes need to be grouped and the order should be timestamp ascending.

Every unique class need to be treated that way - group by class, fill in the missing 5 minute times in order, sum any counts with the exact same timestamp in that group, order by timestamp.  The overall output should be ordered by class ascending.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres makes this particularly easy using a `left join`.  The following has one row per timestamp:

```
select gs.ts, coalesce(sum(t.count), 0)
from generate_series('2020-05-20 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-05-21 23:55:00'::timestamp, interval '5 minute') gs(ts) left join
     t
     on t.timestamp = gs.ts
group by gs.ts;
```

If you want this broken out by class (I really cannot tell what you intend based on the phrasing of the question), then use `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` and aggregation:

```
select c.class, gs.ts, coalesce(sum(t.count), 0)
from generate_series('2020-05-20 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-05-21 23:55:00'::timestamp, interval '5 minute') gs(ts) cross join
     (select distinct class from t) c left join
     t
     on t.timestamp = gs.ts
group by c.class, gs.ts;
```

It occurs to me that the timestamps may not be exact in your data.  If that is the case, use inequalities for the `join`:

```
     on t.timestamp >= gs.ts and
        t.timestamp < gs.ts + interval '5 minute'
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this needs a little tweaking because I wasn't clear enough. The grouping is not happening by class even though it looks that way in the query you wrote.  I should have all 1's then all 2's etc.  Each class should have the entire 24 hour period by 5 minute increments.  What's happening is I'm getting all the distinct classes for 00:00:00 then all the distinct classes for 00:05:00, etc.

Comment: Also, I'm getting all the classes in the table when it should only be the classes that exist within the date interval.  Thanks.

Comment: @emberq . . . Then put a filter in the `c` subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Assume Yours table definition:

```
create table events(
    class       int,
    ts          timestamp,
    cnt         int
);
```

Example query, make everything step by step:

```
with time_range as (
    select timestamp '2020-05-20 00:00:00' as start_time,   -- current_timestamp - interval '2 day'
           timestamp '2020-05-22 00:00:00' as end_time      -- current_timestamp
),
interested_events as (
    select e.class, e.ts, e.cnt
    from events e
    inner join time_range tr
        on (e.ts >= tr.start_time and e.ts < tr.end_time)
),
classes_having_events as (
    select distinct class
    from interested_events
),
periods as (
    select ts as period_start, ts + interval '5 minute' as period_end
    from generate_series(
        (select start_time from time_range), 
        (select end_time from time_range) - interval '1 second',  
        interval '5 minute') ts 
)
select
    c.class, 
    p.period_start ts,
    (select coalesce(sum(cnt), 0) 
    from interested_events e
    where e.class = c.class
      and e.ts >= p.period_start
      and e.ts < p.period_end) as cnt
from classes_having_events as c
cross join periods as p
order by 2, 1;
```

In *time_range* define time interval for witch events should be analyzed.

In *interested_events* events are selected based on previous defined time interval (*time_range* - start_time inclusive, end_time exclusive).

In *classes_having_events* set of classes are created. Every classes with at least one event in choosen time interval are included.

In *periods* there are 5 minute periods created.

Finally we cross join set of classes with periods and for every combination class and period calculate count of events.

Comment: Thanks but I get error relation 'events' does not exist.

Comment: Replace 'events' with Yours table name.